# How to turn off AOT compile in Dynamics AX?

Tags: compilation, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How can I temporary turn off AOT compile dynamics AX? In my *dev* environment.
I can add temporary code in order to jump the compile.

I'm here to ask a trick like to jump Synch, dbSynchronize method, I want to jump the compile too.

I would like to switch off the AOT compile (F7)

[image]

For example, if I import an xpo, I do not want to auto start the compile or skip it in to code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean turn off compile? Do you mean the `CIL`? The compile isn't always running...are you wanting to import XPO's and skip that compile process until you've completed importing several XPO's or something similar? Help us understand the issue/context a little more.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny , I would like to skip XPO compile (F7 command)

Answer (score 5):

The code is located in `\Classes\SysImportElements\import`. I don't think you can disable the compile because it's calling a kernel function in `infolog`. Put a breakpoint in there and import an XPO to see.

You can try commenting out `infolog.endImport(...)`, but I'd be weary of that.

If your need is to disable because you're importing multiple XPO's, you should instead use the Combine XPO tool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/combine-xpo-tool-user-guide

If you want to disable the `F7` key, use a paperclip and you should be able to pop it off your keyboard.

Comment: You should have one more +1 for the paper clip tip.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny

Comment: @ulisses if this answered the question, please mark it answered so it can be closed out.